# What is the difference between declaring a variable using "new" or without using it?

Tags: javascript, oop, function, object

I have this piece of code:

```
function Test() {
  var i=0;
  return {
    foo : function() { console.log(++i); },
    bar : function(a) { i=i+a;console.log(i)} 
  }
}
var test1 = Test();
var test2 = new Test();
```

`test1` and `test2` looks the same, **but my question is if there is anything different between them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` is good for instantiating from a *constructor function*. That basically means, a *new* object is formed which then contains all data that is referenced via `this` within the *constructor*.

Without using `new`, `this` would reference the *global object* and clobber the global namespace (ES3) or it would be `undefined` (ES5 strict).

---

In your particular snippet here, it doesn't matter because you're returning a *new object* nonetheless from `Test()`. That will always be used and assigned to `test1` and `test2`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. Can you do it the first way?

You use the term 'new' because you are declaring a `new` *instance* of an **Object**. Not a variable.